# apacite - citing websites with no author

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, apa-style

So I'm trying to cite a website using `apacite`. According to my teacher, the output has to look like:

> New child vaccine gets funding boost. (2001). Retrieved March 21, 2001, from http://news.ninemsn.com.au/health/story_13178.asp

After finding out `apacite` doesn't allow for `@online`, I added the following to my BiBTeX file

```
@misc{nyu,
  title = {Elements, Atoms, and Molecules},
  year = {1996},
  urldate = {April 1, 2012},
  url = {http://www.nyu.edu/pages/mathmol/textbook/compounds.html}
}
```

but that prints out:

> Elements, atoms, and molecules. (1996).

How do I get it to show URL and retrieved date? I only have 2 websites, so I can enter them manually, but I can't even figure out how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide some more information about your document setup, including which document class you use, and whether you load any citation-related packages (such as `natbib`).

Comment: This is a very useful question for many people (whoever uses APA style and wants to cite a website), and it is very careless of you to have closed it, @lockstep